# On Rouche's theorem: Find the value of $c$ such that $z^5 -3z^2 +1= 0$ has no zeros in $|z| > c$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, rouches-theorem

According to Fundamental theorem of algebra it must have 5 zeros in some region.

If we chose

- $f(z) = z^5$ and
- $g(z)= -3z^2 -1$

Then $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$

This condition is satisfied for the positive integers such that $|z|≥2$.

We chose $|z| = 2$

Then according to *Rouché's theorem*

$f(z)$ and $f(z)+g(z)$ will have same number of zeros inside $|z|=2$

It means that all the five zeros will lie inside $|z| = 2$

And there will be no zeros outside for $|z| > 2$

This was my solution

But according its correct ans is $|z|>2^⅔$

I did not get.

How this could be get.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax commands are nor effective unless they're surrounded by `$` signs.

Comment: It's not enough that the condition b satisfied for positive integers $|z|>2$, it has to be satisfied for complex numbers $|z|>2$

Comment: Yeah right for complex numbers But the question is still unanswered

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
(2^{2/3})^5-3\cdot(2^{2/3})^2-1=8\cdot 2^{1/3}-6\cdot 2^{1/3}-1=2\cdot 2^{2/3}-1>0.
$$
Thus $|z|^5>3|z^2|+1\ge |3z^2-1|$ on the circle $|z|=2^{2/3}$ and
hence $c=2^{2/3}$ works.

You can improve it a little bit, if you replace $c=2^{2/3}$ with $c=1.51<2^{2/3}$, and the same argument works.

In fact, the optimal $c$ is a root of the equation $z^5-3z^2-1=0$, which is equal to
$$
c=1.50941045653627123243833773286186\ldots
$$